# How to check a condition with the help of a database file?

Tags: database, vim

I have a long text file with this format:

```
024 AF Ethiopia text text text text etc
021 XX Germany  text text text text etc
083 AZ India    text text text text etc
...
etc
```

What I want to do is check the continent code of above file
using another text file:
Check if the continent is correct if not change it to correct code.

I have a text file with all countries having this format (Continent Country):

```
AZ Afghanistan
EU Albania
AF Algeria
EU Andorra
AF Angola
AM Argentina
AZ Armenia
OC Australia
EU Austria
 ....
etc
```

Is this possible in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this in a repeatable way and fully automated, I would write a small *Perl* (or *AWK*) script, as these special-purpose languages are better suited than Vimscript (though it would be possible there, too!)

However, for a quick one-time action, I would assemble a search pattern that matches all non-matching lines like this:

```
/^\%(.*\<\%(<C-r>=join(readfile('database.txt'),'\|')<CR>\)\>\)\@!.*$<CR>
```

This reads in the `database.txt` file and creates a regular expression of one branch per line, matched for whole words with `\<...\>`, and using `\@!` to only match lines that do not contain one of the read-in branches. After that, all wrong lines should be highlighted, and you can use `n` to go through them and correct them (manually, though you could employ thesaurus completion (`:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T`) here).

Comment: Hi Ingo, Thank you for your answer 1) I tried your solution, but I'm still receiving this message whatever I do: Pattern not found. 2) Many countries do have XX in my text file. I have to fill in the continent code. Is there a way to insert the continent code when a country has been found?

Comment: What's your resulting pattern (`:echo @/`; perhaps using a subset of your DB)?! Did you perhaps type the `<C-r>` and `<CR>` literally? You need to press Ctrl + R / Enter, resp.

Comment: Yes I inserted it literally. Now I have the correct search but how do I use the code in menu.vim? Is there a way to avoid pressing Ctrl+R in order to put the whole commandline code in menu.vim?

Comment: You should be able to append this after an `:amenu` menu definition. Then, do type all characters literally, like in a mapping. Another way is to use an Ex command: `:let @/ = '^\%(...' . join(...) . '\)...'`.

Comment: this works in amenu `/^\%(.*\%(<C-r>=join(readfile('d:\database.txt'),'\\|')<CR>\)\)\@!.*$<CR>` but i can't make it work in a function. Can you please tell me what will be the code using `let @/ = '^\%(...' . join(...) . '\)...'`?

Comment: sorry this is the correct one `/^\%(.*\<\%(<C-r>=join(readfile('d:\database.txt'),'\\|')<CR>\)\>\)\@!.*$<CR>`